# Awaiting multiple instances of CountDownLatch in container

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I wrote a class `CountDownLatchContainer`  it has a `await()` method, that waits on all CountDownLatches. Everything is working fine.

```
public final class CountDownLatchContainer
{
  private final Set<CountDownLatch> countDowns;

  public CountDownLatchContainer(List<CountDownLatch> countDowns)
  {
    this.countDowns = new HashSet<CountDownLatch>(countDowns);
  }

  public void await() throws InterruptedException
  {
    for (CountDownLatch count : countDowns)
      count.await();
  }
}
```

For the sake of science and art (:D), I wanted to extend the functionality and add the `public boolean await(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` from the `CountDownLatch` class.

I want each countdown latch to have the same timeout and the method overall just to block for the number of `timeout` TimeUnits. I have difficulties achieving that. What I have is:

```
  public boolean await(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException
  {
    boolean success = true;
    for (CountDownLatch count : countDowns)
      success &= count.await(timeout / countDowns.size(), unit);
    return success;
  }
```

So, the overall time out is taken care of, but each count down has just a percentage of the overall time.

**So how can I give the single latches the same amount of time as specified in the method parameter without execeeding the total time?**

Here a visualization. Thx to hexafraction for the ascii art inspiration.

```
|-----------------------------|
             Total
|-----------------------------|
  L1       
|-----------------------------|
  L2       
|-----------------------------|
```

Comment: It would be easier if you used a CyclicBarrier instead...

Comment: I want to map a `CountDownLatch` to a task/goal that needs to be fullfilled. If someone is waiting for a task to complete he awaits a countdownlatch, if he is waiting for several tasks he now could await a countdowncontainer. That's my motivation.

Comment: You could still "wrap" your latches in one CyclicBarrier with n+1 parties - you then call await(timeout) on the first party (your monitor) and call barrier.await() on each other party when the respective latch.await call returns. If the monitoring party reaches the timeout you know that at least one latch did not complete on time. If that makes sense...

Comment: I never worked with `CyclicBarrier` I'll give it a try. It's basically the same as using a latch with a count of `n` as @James showed is his answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Work by awaiting each latch and then seeing how much time remains.

Start by awaiting the first latch for the original time. Note how long it actually took. Remaining time is set to the total minus time took. Now, await the next latch with a limit of the remaining time. Subtract actual. Continue until all latches are awaited or remaining time reaches 0(due to a latch timing out in its remaining time)

```
|-----------------------------|
              Total
|------|----------------------|
  L1       Remaining(1)
|------|---------|------------|
  L1     L2        Remaining(2)
```

and so on... await l1 for total, l2 for remaining(1), etc, etc

Another approach is to timeslice the operation into slices, such as 1 msec each. Loop the latches(marking them as used/removing them via an iterator of a mutable copy of the set could be good) and await for the slice length, until either all latches are released or the time is reached.

Comment: Thought of that, but that is not a fair approach. The first latch would have a advantage.

Comment: @mike What about timeslicing it down to 1-msec slices? Tons of overhead, but possible.

Comment: @mike Does it really have an advantage?  By the time the total time limit is reached, all threads have had the full time to complete and countdown their latch.. unless you are triggering some behaviour during the call to `await()`?

Comment: @increment1 If each latch takes too long to complete, the container would favor completing the first latches due to the fact that the container's `await(` is required to actually complete the latch. Other threads on the first latch would be favored.

Comment: @hexafraction But why does it matter which CountDownLatch fails?  Either they all complete their `await()` or there is a failure.  Which specific latch fails should be irrelevant and calling `await()` should not have any side effect on the latch itself so it should not matter whether the container has called a particular latches `await` or not.

Comment: @increment1 the loop is sequential, not parallel. You should consider that. If the first latch takes too much time before it succeeds, the other don't have the same fair chance of also completing withing the given timebound.

Comment: @mike The loop is, but the threads operating on the CountDownLatches in the set should be operating in parallel.  Every thread operating on one of the latches will have the total timeout time in which to count down their latch.  I.e. The last latch, even if it ends up with an await time of only 1ms, still had all the prior time for its threads to complete before 'await()' is even called by your container.  `await()` does not start the processing of threads using a CountDownLatch, so it does not matter when it is called.

Comment: @mike Of course, my above does not hold if your threads counting down the latches are themselves waiting on the same latches, but even in this case the original solution proposed by hexafraction works since every latch is given as much time to finish as is possible.

Comment: That's not my concern. It's not about the threads counting down the latches. It's about transferring the concept of one latch to a container. I transferred the `await`, I now I want the timeout method to have exactly a duration of let's say 8 seconds. And each latch in the container should have the opportunity to finish within these 8 seconds (as if a normal `await(8, TimeUnit.Seconds)` has been called on them).

Comment: @hexafraction I understand your time slice idea. But that concept is non-blocking. And a little bit against the concept of an awaiting entity. But it should work. Thx. But I'll try to come up with another concept.

Comment: ...I did unterstand your former concept now.

Answer (score 3):

Hexafraction's answer is correct, and far more sane than what I'm about to write, but you don't seem to like it for some reason.  I would write this as a comment, on said answer, but its far too long, and needs some formatting.   Go accept his answer, not this.

With his answer:

L1 gets 8 seconds and finishes at t1.

L2 gets 8 - t1 seconds, plus the t1 seconds while you were waiting on L1, and finishes at t2.

L3 gets 8 - t2 seconds, plus the t2 seconds while you were waiting on L1 and then L2.

...

L_N gets 8 - t_n-1 seconds, plus t_n-1 seconds waiting on the prior tasks.

Note that all of these add up to 8 seconds. Each latch has 8 seconds from the time that the call to await.   In the end, either A) everything finished, and you return right after the last one did, or B) one or more tasks did not finish prior to the timeout.

It is logically the equivalent to the following, but IMHO, much cleaner code:

```
CountDownLatch[] latches;

public void await(final int timeout, final TimeUnit unit) {

  final CountDownLatch metaLatch = new CountDownLatch(latches.length);
  for (final int i = 0; i < latches.length; i++) {
     new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
         latches[i].await(timeout, unit);
         metaLatch.countDown();
       }
     }.start();
  }

  metaLatch.await(timeout, unit); 
}
```

You appear to be hung up on the fact that the timeout calls aren't exactly the same - but they can't be if you're going to do it serially, and they don't need to be. They are an implementation detail - each latch still gets 8s to run from the start of the call, which is what the contract of await(...) says. You requested an 8s timeout, and you get an 8s timeout.  If all latches fired, it succeeds, if not, it fails, which is what you'd expect.

If you want to do it in parallel as above (plus a load of error handling which I've left out for brevity), you can, but quite honestly that is unnecessarily complicated for code that accomplishes the same thing as hexa's answer.

If none of this answers it, you might need to go back an edit to explain what you really mean, because I suspect you're leaving something out.

Comment: Thx for the explanation. Yes, I really was hung up on the differing calls of await.

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to implement a non-blocking container version of `await(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`.

```
public final class CountDownLatchContainer {
    private final Set<CountDownLatch> countDowns;

    public CountDownLatchContainer(List<CountDownLatch> countDowns) {
        this.countDowns = new HashSet<CountDownLatch>(countDowns);
    }

    public void await() throws InterruptedException {
        for (CountDownLatch count : countDowns)
            count.await();
    }

    public boolean await(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
            throws InterruptedException{
        boolean success = true;
        ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(countDowns.size());
        List<Future<Boolean>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Boolean>>(countDowns.size());

        for (CountDownLatch count : countDowns)
            futures.add(e.submit(new SingleLatchTimeOutAwaiter(count, timeout, unit)));

        for (Future<Boolean> f : futures) {
            try {
                success &= f.get();
            } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
                throw new InterruptedException();
            }
        }
        e.shutdown();
        return success;
    }

    private static class SingleLatchTimeOutAwaiter implements Callable<Boolean> {
        private final CountDownLatch count;
        private final long timeout;
        private final TimeUnit unit;

        private SingleLatchTimeOutAwaiter(CountDownLatch count, long timeout,
                TimeUnit unit) {
            this.count = count;
            this.timeout = timeout;
            this.unit = unit;
        }

        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            return count.await(timeout, unit);
        }
    }
}
```

---

And here a test case. It's pretty accurate.

```
public class CountDownLatchContainerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        CountDownLatch c1 = new CountDownLatch(1);
        CountDownLatch c2 = new CountDownLatch(1);

        CountDownLatchContainer c = new CountDownLatchContainer(Arrays.asList(
                c1, c2));
        e.submit(new MultiWaiter(c, 4, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        e.submit(new MultiWaiter(c, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        e.submit(new MultiWaiter(c, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

        c1.countDown();
        int hundredth = 29; // 1/100 s delay
        for (int i = hundredth; i --> 0;) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        c2.countDown();
        e.shutdown();
    }

    private static class MultiWaiter implements Callable<Void> {
        private static final AtomicInteger instanceCounter = new AtomicInteger(
                0);
        private final int instance;

        private final CountDownLatchContainer c;
        private final long timeout;
        private final TimeUnit unit;

        private MultiWaiter(CountDownLatchContainer c, long timeout,
                TimeUnit unit) {
            this.c = c;
            this.timeout = timeout;
            this.unit = unit;
            this.instance = instanceCounter.getAndIncrement();
        }

        public Void call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName() + "#" + instance
                    + " is waiting...");
            System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName() + "#" + instance
                    + " is in time: " + c.await(timeout, unit));
            System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName() + "#" + instance
                    + " is released!");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

> MultiWaiter#0 is waiting...
>   MultiWaiter#1 is waiting...
>   MultiWaiter#2 is waiting...
>   MultiWaiter#1 is in time: false
>   MultiWaiter#1 is released!
>   MultiWaiter#0 is in time: true
>   MultiWaiter#0 is released!
>   MultiWaiter#2 is in time: true
>   MultiWaiter#2 is released!

Comment: Since one is always waiting on the same latches in one particular container, the `futures` list could be made an instance variable of the container, to make further calls faster (I guess I would have to be `volatile`).

Comment: Tried it...bad idea. Since then the await parameters would be permanently stored. The use of a concurrent map that stores list of futures as value for each key tuple (timeout, unit) seems to be better.